# Merge array without loss key index

Tags: php, arrays

i have two array

```
/**
 * Menu Navigation
 * @var array
 */
public $nav_top = array(
    100 => 'Dashboard',
    200 => 'Sell',
    300 => 'Products',
    400 => 'History',
    500 => 'Customers',
    600 => 'Setup'
);

/**
 * Menu Navigation
 * @var array
 */
public $nav_sub = array(
    201 => 'Current Sale',
    202 => 'Retrieve Sale',
    203 => 'Close Register',

    301 => 'Product',
    302 => 'Stock Control',
    303 => 'Price Books',
    304 => 'Types',
    305 => 'Suppliers',
    306 => 'Brands',
    307 => 'Tags',

    501 => 'Customer',
    502 => 'Group'
);
```

How to combine this two array without losing it's key index?

if i do it with `array_merge()` the index will restart from zero

```
$nav = array_merge($Class->nav_top, $Class->nav_sub);
var_dump($nav);

# Output:
array(
    0 => 'Current Sale',
    1 => 'Retrieve Sale',
    2 => 'Close Register',
    .......
);
```

expected result the array key still same

```
# Expected Output
array(
    100 => 'Dashboard',
    200 => 'Sell',
    300 => 'Products',
    ........
);
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The easiest I can think of:

```
$combined = $nav_top + $nav_sub;
```

[An example](http://codepad.org/PQ2cZBzO).

Comment: +1 i never knew + can work on array .. are you sure its not a bug ... lol

Comment: @Baba no bug. Really :-) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: @Baba, not a bug at all and has been [documented](http://php.net/operators.array) for around a decade.

Comment: Thanks, it save my time.

Comment: Note that the order is important. with `array_merge($a,$b)`, keys in `$b` will override matching keys in `$a`.  Where with `$a+$b`, keys in `$b` will NOT override matching keys in `$a`, but they will be ignored. It's explained in this example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php#example-5418

Answer (score 1):

### MY advice

use `jeroen` Solution

### Hard way out

```
$combined  = merge($nav_top,$nav_sub);
```

Function

```
function merge($arr1,$arr2)
{
    if(!is_array($arr1))
        $arr1 = array();
    if(!is_array($arr2))
        $arr2 = array();
    $keys1 = array_keys($arr1);
    $keys2 = array_keys($arr2);
    $keys  = array_merge($keys1,$keys2);
    $vals1 = array_values($arr1);
    $vals2 = array_values($arr2);
    $vals  = array_merge($vals1,$vals2);
    $ret    = array();

    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
        list($unused,$val) = each($vals);
        $ret[$key] = $val;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Or

```
function merge($a1, $a2) {

    $aRes = $a1;
    foreach ( array_slice ( func_get_args (), 1 ) as $aRay ) {
        foreach ( array_intersect_key ( $aRay, $aRes ) as $key => $val )
            $aRes [$key] += $val;
        $aRes += $aRay;
    }
    return $aRes;
}
```

Demo : http://codepad.org/9B8V96Gf