# Multidimensional array directory map

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, directory, directory-structure

I'm trying to get a directory structure in a multidimensional array.

I got this far:

```
function dirtree($dir, $regex = '', $ignoreEmpty = false)
{
    if (!$dir instanceof DirectoryIterator) {
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator((string) $dir);
    }
    $dirs = array();
    $files = array();
    foreach ($dir as $node) {
        if ($node->isDir() && !$node->isDot()) {
            $tree = dirtree($node->getPathname(), $regex, $ignoreEmpty);
            if (!$ignoreEmpty || count($tree)) {
                $dirs[$node->getFilename()] = $tree;
            }
        } elseif ($node->isFile()) {
            $name = $node->getFilename();
            if ('' == $regex || preg_match($regex, $name)) {
                $files[] = $name;
            }
        }
    }
    asort($dirs);
    sort($files);
    return array_merge($dirs, $files);
}
```

But I am having issues getting the folder name instead of the index 0,1 .etc. *This seems to be due to the fact that my directories have numeric names?*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array  // 0 should be the folder name
        (
            [0] => m_109225488_1.jpg
            [1] => t_109225488_1.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => m_252543961_1.jpg
            [1] => t_252543961_1.jpg
        )
```

Comment: Can you add `var_dump`  `$dirs`, `$files` and expected output  here ?

Comment: Hmm... How is `array_merge` not working? When I run your code I get the directories keyed by name as expected. `array_merge` should preserve string keys...

Comment: Apparently, it was because my directories had numeric names... Just realized that now thanks to a comment on my answer otherwise I would have put that in the question

Comment: In the case of `array_merge()` the numeric keys would be incremented during the merge. This means you could detect what was a directory vs regular file by checking if the mapped value is either a scalar or array. For example, it a directory `0` is read, then the first file will be keyed under `1`. You can distinguish them by checking if `$result[0]` is an array or scalar.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was rather simple thanks to: [Merge array without loss key index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305912/merge-array-without-loss-key-index)

Instead of `array_merge` simply do `$dirs + $files`

Potential solution (potential issue point out by Roger Gee):

```
function dirtree($dir, $regex = '', $ignoreEmpty = false)
{
    if (!$dir instanceof DirectoryIterator) {
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator((string) $dir);
    }
    $dirs = array();
    $files = array();
    foreach ($dir as $node) {
        if ($node->isDir() && !$node->isDot()) {
            $tree = dirtree($node->getPathname(), $regex, $ignoreEmpty);
            if (!$ignoreEmpty || count($tree)) {
                $dirs[$node->getFilename()] = $tree;
            }
        } elseif ($node->isFile()) {
            $name = $node->getFilename();
            if ('' == $regex || preg_match($regex, $name)) {
                $files[] = $name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $dirs + $files;
}
```

Better solution?

```
function dirtree($dir, $regex = '', $ignoreEmpty = false)
{
    if (!$dir instanceof DirectoryIterator) {
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator((string) $dir);
    }
    $filedata = array();
    foreach ($dir as $node) {
        if ($node->isDir() && !$node->isDot()) {
            $tree = dirtree($node->getPathname(), $regex, $ignoreEmpty);
            if (!$ignoreEmpty || count($tree)) {
                $filedata[$node->getFilename()] = $tree;
            }
        } elseif ($node->isFile()) {
            $name = $node->getFilename();
            if ('' == $regex || preg_match($regex, $name)) {
                $filedata[] = $name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $filedata;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution I was trying to figure out one. your folder names had numeric names, right?

Comment: They did, and those were the only ones that didn't work now that you mention it, that was probably the cause in the first place.

Comment: Caution: If you have a directory named `0` or `1` or any numeric index this may cause some files to not appear in the list since they will be excluded during the array union. Note that PHP's `+` operator is a union of the keys, not the values; the left operand is preferred over the right operand, meaning elements from the right operand may be ignored. In your previous example using `array_merge` this wasn't an issue. The documentation on `array_merge` states that numeric keys are not overwritten.

Comment: @RogerGee my directories (atleast the ones in question for this operation) all have unique numeric names like 123456 and 123457 .etc. There doesn't seem to be any missing files even though they are numeric?

Comment: Yes, array_merge re-index's the numeric keys. [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):  *"Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array"*

Comment: And the reindexing is what makes `array_merge` ideal. It won't cause files to be ignored, just reindexed. Then you can check to see if the value is an array or scalar to differentiate directory vs regular file.

Comment: But then what if you are in my situation and want to have the directory names as the array keys when they are numeric

Comment: You might consider a special bucket for regular files. See my answer. If it's not too burdensome, you can always filter the keys by the ones that map to an array.

Comment: Well you see I don't really need a special bucket in the first place for either dirs or files. Perhaps my updated solution is the better?

Comment: The only issue I see with the updated solution is the order in which the directory entries are read. If a regular file is read first, followed by a directory named `0`,then the file entry would get overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Using the array union operation is dangerous since you can potentially overwrite existing files. Consider the following directory structure:

```
a       <-- directory
├── 0   <-- directory (empty)
├── b   <-- regular file
└── c   <-- directory
    └── d   <-- regular file
```

Now consider running the operation using the array union. I get the following result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["c"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
}
```

Notice how regular file `b` is not present? This is because the array union operation prefers the existing `0` index over the `0` index from the right operand (which contains the regular files).

I would stick with the original implementation present in the question *or* use a special bucket for files that doesn't contain a valid filesystem name (e.g. `:files:`). Note that this may be platform-specific as to what you choose.

In the case of the original implementation, you can decide whether the index is a directory vs regular file by calling `is_array` or `is_scalar` on the value. Note that since the directories array is the first parameter to `array_merge`, you are guaranteed that no directory indexes get incremented and will always refer to the correct directory names.

Here's how you could determine just the directory names:

```
function getDirectoryNames($result) {
    $ds = [];
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $ds[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $ds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is ksort instead of asort.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
function dirtree($dir, $regex = '', $ignoreEmpty = false)
{
    if (!$dir instanceof DirectoryIterator) {
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator((string) $dir);
    }
    $dirs = array();
    $files = array();
    foreach ($dir as $node) {
        if ($node->isDir() && !$node->isDot()) {
            $tree = dirtree($node->getPathname(), $regex, $ignoreEmpty);
            if (!$ignoreEmpty || count($tree)) {
                $dirs[$node->getFilename()] = $tree;
            }
        } elseif ($node->isFile()) {
            $name = $node->getFilename();
            if ('' == $regex || preg_match($regex, $name)) {
                $files[] = $name;
            }
        }
    }
    ksort($dirs);
    sort($files);
    return array_merge($dirs, $files);
}
?>
<body>
<pre>
<?=var_dump(dirtree(getcwd());?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This will do the work for you.
But as mentioned, a better solution would be to seperate directories and files like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
class DirNode {
    public $name;
    public $dirs=[];
    public $files=[];

    public function DirNode($dirName) {
        $this->name = $dirName;
    }

    public function printDir($prefix="") {
        echo($prefix.$this->name."\n");
        foreach($this->dirs as $dir=>$subDir) {
            echo($prefix.$dir."\n");
            $subDir->printDir($prefix."    ");
            echo("\n");
        }
        foreach($this->files as $file) {
            echo($prefix.$file."\n");
        }
    }
}

function dirtree($dir, $regex = '', $ignoreEmpty = false)
{
    if (!$dir instanceof DirectoryIterator) {
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator((string) $dir);
    }
    $directory = new DirNode($dir);
    foreach ($dir as $node) {
        if ($node->isDir() && !$node->isDot()) {
            $tree = dirtree($node->getPathname(), $regex, $ignoreEmpty);
            if (!$ignoreEmpty || count($tree)) {
                $directory->dirs[$node->getFilename()] = $tree;
            }
        } elseif ($node->isFile()) {
            $name = $node->getFilename();
            if ('' == $regex || preg_match($regex, $name)) {
                $directory->files[] = $name;
            }
        }
    }
    ksort($directory->dirs);
    sort($directory->files);
    return $directory;
}

$dirfiles = dirtree(getcwd().'/..');

echo("<pre>");
echo($dirfiles->printDir());
echo("</pre>");

?>
</body>
</html>
```